# personal messaging system not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm adding a Personal messaging system to my site. I have 2 tables: one for users and one for messages. I have 3 php files, one to see the list of your messages, one to make a new one and one to read the file.

The databases are working well, but the list does not show anything (0 messages). can anybody see the error? I guess it should be in one of my queries. Thanks

First file list_pm.php:

```
 <?php
    //We check if the user is logged
    if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
//We list his messages in a table

//Two queries are executes, one for the unread messages and another for read messages

$req1 = mysqli_query($link,'select m1.id, m1.title, m1.timestamp, count(m2.id) as reps, users.id as userid, users.email from pm as m1, pm as m2,users where ((m1.user1="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" and m1.user1read="no" and users.id=m1.user2 ) or (m1.user2="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" and m1.user2read="no" and users.id=m1.user1)) and m1.id2="1" and m2.id=m1.id group by m1.id order by m1.id desc');

$req2 = mysqli_query($link,'select m1.id, m1.title, m1.timestamp, count(m2.id) as reps, users.id as userid, users.email from pm as m1, pm as m2,users where ((m1.user1="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" and m1.user1read="yes" and users.id=m1.user2) or (m1.user2="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" and m1.user2read="yes" and users.id=m1.user1)) and m1.id2="1" and m2.id=m1.id group by m1.id order by m1.id desc');

?>

This is the list of your messages:<br />
<a href="new_pm.php" class="link_new_pm">New PM</a><br />
<h3>Unread Messages(<?php echo intval(mysqli_num_rows($req1)); ?>):</h3>
<table>
        <tr>
        <th class="title_cell">Title</th>
        <th>Nb. Replies</th>
        <th>Participant</th>
        <th>Date of creation</th>
    </tr>
<?php

//We display the list of unread messages

while($dn1 = mysqli_fetch_array($req1))
{
?>
        <tr>
        <td class="left"><a href="read_pm.php?id=<?php echo $dn1['id']; ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($dn1['title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $dn1['reps']-1; ?></td>
        <td><a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $dn1['userid']; ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($dn1['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s' ,$dn1['timestamp']); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
//If there is no unread message we notice it
if(intval(mysqli_num_rows($req1))==0)
{
?>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="center">You have no unread message.</td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
<br />
<h3>Read Messages(<?php echo intval(mysqli_num_rows($req2)); ?>):</h3>
<table>
        <tr>
        <th class="title_cell">Title</th>
        <th>Nb. Replies</th>
        <th>Participant</th>
        <th>Date or creation</th>
    </tr>
<?php
//We display the list of read messages
while($dn2 = mysqli_fetch_array($req2))
{
?>
        <tr>
        <td class="left"><a href="read_pm.php?id=<?php echo $dn2['id']; ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($dn2['title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $dn2['reps']-1; ?></td>
        <td><a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $dn2['userid']; ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($dn2['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s' ,$dn2['timestamp']); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
//If there is no read message we notice it
if(intval(mysqli_num_rows($req2))==0)
{
?>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="center">You have no read message.</td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
<?php
}
else
{
        echo 'You must be logged to access this page.';
}
?>
```

//Second file to make a new pm : new_pm.php

```
<?php
//We check if the user is logged
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
$form = true;
$otitle = '';
$orecip = '';
$omessage = '';
//We check if the form has been sent
if(isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['recip'], $_POST['message']))
{
        $otitle = $_POST['title'];
        $orecip = $_POST['recip'];
        $omessage = $_POST['message'];

        //We remove slashes depending on the configuration

            if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {       
                //$otitle = stripslashes($otitle);
                //$orecip = stripslashes($orecip);
                //$omessage = stripslashes($omessage);
        }

        //We check if all the fields are filled

        if($_POST['title']!='' and $_POST['recip']!='' and $_POST['message']!='')
        {
                //We protect the variables

               // $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($otitle);
                //$recip = mysqli_real_escape_string($orecip);
               // $message = mysqli_real_escape_string(nl2br(htmlentities($omessage, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));

                //We check if the recipient exists

                $dn1 = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link,'select count(id) as recip, id as recipid , (select count(*) from pm) as npm from users where email ="'.$orecip.'"'));

                if($dn1['recip']==1)

                {
                        //We check if the recipient is not the actual user

                        if($dn1['recipid']!=$_SESSION['id'])
                        {
                                $id = $dn1['npm']+1;

                                //We send the message

                                if(mysqli_query($link,'insert into pm (id, id2, title, user1, user2, message, timestamp, user1read, user2read)values("'.$id.'", "1", "'.$otitle.'", "'.$_SESSION['id'].'", "'.$dn1['recipid'].'", "'.$omessage.'", "'.time().'", "yes", "no")'))
                                {
?>
<div class="message">The message has successfully been sent.<br />
<a href="list_pm.php">List of my Personal messages</a></div>
<?php
                                        $form = false;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                        //Otherwise, we say that an error occured
                                        $error = 'An error occurred while sending the message';
                                }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                //Otherwise, we say the user cannot send a message to himself
                                $error = 'You cannot send a message to yourself.';
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                        //Otherwise, we say the recipient does not exists
                        $error = 'The recipient does not exists.';
                }
        }
        else
        {
                //Otherwise, we say a field is empty
                $error = 'A field is empty. Please fill of the fields.';
        }
}
elseif(isset($_GET['recip']))
{
        //We get the username for the recipient if available
        $orecip = $_GET['recip'];
}
if($form)
{
//We display a message if necessary
if(isset($error))
{
        echo '<div class="message">'.$error.'</div>';
}
//We display the form
?>
<div class="content">
        <h1>New Personal Message</h1>
    <form action="new_pm.php" method="post">
                Please fill the following form to send a Personal message.<br />
        <label for="title">Title</label><input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($otitle, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" id="title" name="title" /><br />
        <label for="recip">Recipient<span class="small">(UserEmail)</span></label><input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($orecip, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" id="recip" name="recip" /><br />
        <label for="message">Message</label><textarea cols="40" rows="5" id="message" name="message"><?php echo htmlentities($omessage, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
</div>
<?php
}
}
else
{
        echo '<div class="message">You must be logged to access this page.</div>';
}
?>
```

and the last one to read the message read_pm.php:

```
<?php
//We check if the user is logged
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
//We check if the ID of the discussion is defined
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id = intval($_GET['id']);

//We get the title and the narators of the discussion

$req1 = mysqli_query($link,'select title, user1, user2 from pm where id="'.$id.'" and id2="1"');
$dn1 = mysqli_fetch_array($req1);

//We check if the discussion exists

if(mysqli_num_rows($req1)==1)
{
//We check if the user have the right to read this discussion

if($dn1['user1']==$_SESSION['id'] or $dn1['user2']==$_SESSION['id'])
{
//The discussion will be placed in read messages

if($dn1['user1']==$_SESSION['id'])
{
        mysqli_query($link,'update pm set user1read="yes" where id="'.$id.'" and id2="1"');
        $user_partic = 2;
}
else
{
        mysqli_query($link,'update pm set user2read="yes" where id="'.$id.'" and id2="1"');
        $user_partic = 1;
}

//We get the list of the messages

$req2 = mysqli_query($link,'select pm.timestamp, pm.message, users.id as userid, users.username, users.avatar from pm, users where pm.id="'.$id.'" and users.id=pm.user1 order by pm.id2');

//We check if the form has been sent

if(isset($_POST['message']) and $_POST['message']!='')
{
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        //We remove slashes depending on the configuration

        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
                $message = stripslashes($message);
        }
        //We protect the variables

        $message = mysqli_real_escape_string(nl2br(htmlentities($message, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));

        //We send the message and we change the status of the discussion to unread for the recipient

        if(mysqli_query($link,'insert into pm (id, id2, title, user1, user2, message, timestamp, user1read, user2read)values("'.$id.'", "'.(intval(mysqli_num_rows($req2))+1).'", "", "'.$_SESSION['userid'].'", "", "'.$message.'", "'.time().'", "", "")') and mysqli_query($link,'update pm set user'.$user_partic.'read="yes" where id="'.$id.'" and id2="1"'))
        {
?>
<div class="message">Your message has successfully been sent.<br />
<a href="read_pm.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">Go to the discussion</a></div>
<?php
        }
        else
        {
?>
<div class="message">An error occurred while sending the message.<br />
<a href="read_pm.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">Go to the discussion</a></div>
<?php
        }
}
else
{
//We display the messages
?>
<div class="content">
<h1><?php echo $dn1['title']; ?></h1>
<table class="messages_table">
        <tr>
        <th class="author">User</th>
        <th>Message</th>
    </tr>
<?php
while($dn2 = mysql_fetch_array($req2))
{
?>

        <tr>
        <td class="author center"><?php
if($dn2['avatar']!='')
{
        echo '<img src="'.htmlentities($dn2['avatar']).'" alt="Image Perso" style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px;" />';
}
?><br /><a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $dn2['userid']; ?>"><?php echo $dn2['email']; ?></a></td>
        <td class="left"><div class="date">Sent: <?php echo date('m/d/Y H:i:s' ,$dn2['timestamp']); ?></div>
        <?php echo $dn2['message']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
//We display the reply form
?>
</table><br />
<h2>Reply</h2>
<div class="center">
    <form action="read_pm.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post">
        <label for="message" class="center">Message</label><br />
        <textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="message" id="message"></textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}
}
else
{
        echo '<div class="message">You dont have the rights to access this page.</div>';
}
}
else
{
        echo '<div class="message">This discussion does not exists.</div>';
}
}
else
{
        echo '<div class="message">The discussion ID is not defined.</div>';
}
}
else
{
        echo '<div class="message">You must be logged to access this page.</div>';
}
?>
```

the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `pm` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `id2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `user1` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `user2` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `user1read` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `user2read` varchar(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Really appreciate the help guys

Comment: read_pm.php your mixing mysql and mysqli, this will not work you have to use one or the other

Comment: is the main issue within `list_pm.php`?

Comment: Please post your pm table structure

Comment: Will you be please more specific on how i'm mixing mysql and mysqli , thx

Comment: You are querying the database all the way through using mysqli_query and other functions,  half way through the last file you start using mysql_query and other functions, the are two completely different methods and they do not work together

Comment: Adam means your read_pm.php file insert query...

Comment: Oh yeah got it , really appreciate the help but except that is there any problem in list_pm.php? anything you nitice?